# If case only checks one of the things

Tags: android, kotlin

This code accepts either one, what i need is for both of them to be checked and return. Where am i making the mistake?

```
 if(!email.endsWith(".com") && !email.contains("@")) {
                Toast.makeText(view.context,
                      "Please enter a correct email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I think that you might need a [xnor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate), is that correct?

Comment: No i need And. If one of them is wrong it's wrong, they both have to be correct. But right now it accepts it like it's an Or gate. @CcmU

Comment: @KeremE. If both have to be correct, then the good case is `AND`, and the bad case is the negation of the good case. Google it how to negate logical statements in math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the AND to a OR.

```
if(!email.endsWith(".com") || !email.contains("@")) {
                Toast.makeText(view.context,
                      "Please enter a correct email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: No i need And. If one of them is wrong it's wrong, they both have to be correct. But right now it accepts it like it's an Or gate.

Comment: @KeremE. just try it before saying it's wrong. It really works

Comment: Wow.. It actually worked but it doesn't make any sense, can you explain it? If i need AND, why does using OR works?

Comment: @KeremE. it actually also could have been written with an AND like `if(!(email.endsWith(".com") && email.contains("@")))`. But you are checking negatives so if EITHER is negative you want to toast. EITHER translates to OR

Comment: Because it's a NAND: `!A || !B` is equal to `! (A && B)`. You need to enter in the `if` clause, as you mentioned above, whether one of the two condition is wrong. So you'll need to NOT enter when `email.endsWith(".com")` and `email.contains("@")` are both `true`. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Binary_operations) you can find some truth tables that could possibly help you understand better.

Comment: Oh that makes much more sense now thank you guys!